# Typescript module definitions for existing javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

So i'm trying to convert a large javascript project to typescript and I was wondering if I could take advantage of declaration files to do it.

Simplified config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types/",
            "./typings/modules/"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

And say I have the following file structure:

```
src
  | components
    | textComponent.jsx
  | containers
    | loginContainer.tsx
typings
  | modules
    | redux-saga
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like this in loginContainer.tsx

```
import TextComponent from 'components/textComponent';
```

and it to retrieve the typing information from something like `typings/modules/components/textComponent.d.ts`. I suspect this might be an abuse of `baseUrl` config option and module declarations.

Is this even possible? Can i provide typing information for imported, non-npm modules, without touching the original javascript?

Comment: why not just use the `allowJs`?

Comment: @gilamran I have allowJs but there is an issue with importing jsx into ts (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17104) which prevents from benefiting from the types. Also, allowJs does typescript "best guess". I thought there might be a way to add more information, given I know what to expect from these modules.

Comment: So how about renaming all js to ts, and jsx to tsx?

Comment: Renaming all files will likely cause type failures for most of those files (React classes need generics for prop types and state types) and I intend to use type checking to prevent PRs from being merged. For a large project, converting all jsx to tsx just doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever find solution? I'm still trying to accomplish the same thing.  There's a related [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35296) about emitting custom type definitions.  I have an [example repository](https://github.com/restjohn/typescript_custom_dts_issue) that demonstrates the issue as well, but so far I've not gotten any TypeScript project developers to respond in any meaningful way.

Comment: No unfortunately not, just had to do it manually, progressively.